# Calling HttpRequest with Drush produce PHP fatal error

Tags: drush, emails

I created a drush command which call a function which send emails.
When I'm calling this method with the devel help module, the function is called correctly and my emails are sent. But when I tried to call it from a drush command I have this error below :

> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   [error] Error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found

Here is how I instanciate my HttpRequest class :

```
// Configuration client Http
$clientHttp = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_POST);
```

I am working on my local environment with WAMP (PHP 5.2.11).

I will be very happy if you can give me some advice, thanks !

Comment: That's not a core php class, unless you have pecl_http installed it won't be available. Perhaps it's just not enabled for cli?